# Upload folder using Google Drive PHP API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to upload a folder of files to Google Drive, using the PHP API. I can upload a single file to my Google Drive, but can't seem to upload a folder of files...e.g. a folder containing some Word documents and PDFs. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: why can't you just `foreach($yourfolder as $file) { upload($file); }`-type thing?

Comment: As far as I know, the API does not support what you want. You can just create a folder, insert a file into a folder or move files between folders. Please check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder).

Comment: Thanks...seems that way. I could go for the foreach option but I wanted to be able to just upload a folder containing any set of files.

Answer (score 0):

> [Files: insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) Insert **A** new file

In instances like this the documentation can be a big help.   File.insert is for inserting A file as in one singular.  If you want to insert more then one I suggest you look into using a loop and looping over each of the file you would like to upload.

Tip:

setting the mime type as follows creates the initial folder

```
mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

Note the file id when that is created and set the parent of the files up upload to that and they will be uploaded into that directory.

Comment: Thanks...I'd looked at the documentation but it didn't seem that I could just upload a folder containing any files. I also want to be able to upload zip files but it doesn't seem that's possible either

Comment: You can insert a new folder remember with drive folders are also considered to be files they just have the application/vnd.google-apis.folder mime type. You can insert a zip file into the folder.  Drive doesn't care what the file type is just upload it.

Comment: DaimTo, what exactly are you getting at in this answer; it's quite confusing, to me. How would falsely changing the MIME-type of a file to a folder help for uploading a folder of files? Would you zip the folder, and upload it with the folder mime-type? Would google then convert it into a folder?